# Diferença de horas consulta sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho os seguintes dados:

```
2016-10-13 09:04:00.000  1
2016-10-13 20:33:00.000  4
2016-10-14 09:10:00.000  1
2016-10-14 21:04:00.000  4
2016-10-17 09:04:00.000  1
2016-10-17 19:50:00.000  4
```

Como saber a diferença entre horas entre entre o 4 e o 1,exemplo:

```
2016-10-13 09:04:00.000  1
2016-10-13 20:33:00.000  4
```

Meu resulta esperado seria por volta de 14 horas,de acordo com exemplo:

```
20:33
21:33
22:33
23:33
00:33
01:33
02:33
03:33
04:33
05:33
06:33
07:33
08:33
09:04
```

Ou seja o `numero 4 é o final` e o `numero 1 é o inicio`,preciso saber a `diferença entre  final e o inicio`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Use o DATEDIFF

```
SELECT DATEDIFF ( HOUR , '2016-10-13 09:04:00.000' , '2016-10-13 20:33:00.000' ) Diferenca
```

Answer (score 1):

Tentei postar no SQL Fiddle mais ta dando erro,segue minha solução:

EXEMPLO TABELA:

```
create table #dados (
    cpf int,
    data datetime ,
    tipo int
)
```

EXEMPLO INSERT:

```
insert into #dados (cpf, data, tipo) values
(11111111111, '2016-10-13 09:04:00.000',  1),
(11111111111, '2016-10-13 20:33:00.000',  4),
(33333333333, '2016-10-14 09:10:00.000',  1),
(33333333333, '2016-10-14 21:04:00.000',  4),
(55555555555, '2016-10-17 09:04:00.000',  1),
(55555555555, '2016-10-17 19:50:00.000',  4)
```

USEI O CPF PARA PODER AGRUPAR:

```
Agrupei por cpf, pegando a menor data e comparando com a maior data

        select cpf, datediff(hh, min(data), max(data)) as horas
            from #dados
            group by cpf
```

Agradecimentos: @Thiago Henrique e Leonardo Caetano