# Diferença de dias entre registros e exibir somente os resultados > que 14

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
 SELECT 
    V.CHAPA,
    F.NOME,
    V.DATA,
    DATENAME(dw,V.DATA) AS DIA,
    MAX(V.SEQUENCIALBATIDA) AS BATIDA
      FROM
            ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW AS V
            LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC  AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
        WHERE
            V.CHAPA = 123
        AND DATEPART(dw,V.DATA) = 1
        AND BATIDA IS NOT NULL 
        AND V.CODCOLIGADA = 1 
        AND  YEAR ( V.DATA ) = 2016 
        AND MONTH ( V.DATA ) = 9
         GROUP BY V.CHAPA,
                  F.NOME,
                  V.DATA 
          ORDER BY V.DATA ASC
```

Ela retorna:

```
123 JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-04 00:00:00.000 Sunday  2
123 JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-11 00:00:00.000 Sunday  2
123 JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-25 00:00:00.000 Sunday  2
```

Preciso saber a `diferença de dias entre cada registro` e só exibir os registros onde a `diferença` for `maior que 14`

```
BD: SQL SERVER
```

> De acordo com a dica de @GOKU SSJGod

```
123 JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-04 00:00:00.000 Sunday  2
>>>>> 123 JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-11 00:00:00.000 Sunday  2
123 JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-25 00:00:00.000 Sunday  2
```

> Ela ta fazendo o calculo, só que esta calculando a diferença entre a 1
>   e a ultima no caso desconsiderando a 2.  Preciso que calcule a
>   diferença entre todos os registros algo como DATEDIFF(data_atual -
>   data_anterior)

Comment: Possível duplicata da sua anterior [Diferença de horas consulta sql server](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159596/diferen%c3%a7a-de-horas-consulta-sql-server)? Acho que o fato de ter aceito uma resposta que não responde o que foi perguntado não ajuda muito naquele caso, é importante de fato resolver cada passo. Resolvida aquela, fazer um WHERE diferenca > 14 é o de menos.

Comment: Na verdade naquele lá eu tinha o os status 1 e 4 onde trabalhei com eles e deu certo, nesse caso é tudo igual onde a unica diferença são as datas,com isso se eu usa-se o date diff não daria certo.

Comment: seria bom definir o db usado na questão, pode fazer diferença pra comparar entre linhas.

Comment: A propósito, não consigo ver como é que o DATEDIFF poderia resolver aquela questão, sendo que são linhas diferentes (é o mesmo problema que essa aqui). Se conseguiu, seria bom postar uma resposta naquela mostrando como fez, ajudaria outras pessoas.

Comment: Solução postada, por favor verificar e me retorne sua opinião.

Comment: Se fosse naquela, seria o caso de por um HAVING horas > 14 no final, pq é agrupamento. Se é entre linhas, sem agrupar, vai precisar de algum tipo de variável. No MySQL seria @var = algumacoisa (pra guardar a linha anterior para comparação). No T-SQL não sei como é.

Comment: Blza,vou dar uma pesquisada sobre o que você disse,caso consiga,posto a solução. Obrigado !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue solução:

```
-- código #1
with
Consulta as (
 SELECT 
    V.CHAPA,
    F.NOME,
    V.DATA,
    DATENAME(dw,V.DATA) AS DIA,
    MAX(V.SEQUENCIALBATIDA) AS BATIDA
      FROM
            ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW AS V
            LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC  AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
        WHERE
            V.CHAPA = 123
        AND DATEPART(dw,V.DATA) = 1
        AND BATIDA IS NOT NULL 
        AND V.CODCOLIGADA = 1 
        AND  YEAR ( V.DATA ) = 2016 
        AND MONTH ( V.DATA ) = 9
         GROUP BY V.CHAPA,
                  F.NOME,
                  V.DATA 
),
ConsultaSeq as (
SELECT *, Seq= row_number() over (partition by CHAPA order by DATA)
  from Consulta
)
SELECT C1.CHAPA, C1.NOME, C1.DATA, C2.DATA, DateDiff(day, C1.DATA, C2.DATA) as Dias
  from ConsultaSeq as C1
       left join ConsultaSeq as C2 on C1.CHAPA = C2.CHAPA and C1.Seq = C2.Seq -1
  where DateDiff(day, C1.DATA, C2.DATA) > 14;
```